# Произойдёт ли утечка памяти?

Tags: память, указатели, c++

```
int *p1=new int;
int *p2=new int;
p1=p2;
```

В итоге `p1` и `p2` будут указывать на один и тот же участок памяти. Произойдёт ли утечка памяти, занятой сначала `p1`. Если да, то как этого избежать?

Comment: Вы уверены насчёт `new` в чистом C?

Comment: В Си нет `new`. Это С++.

Утечка произойдет. Избежать просто - думать и внимательно писать программы.

Answer (score 3):

Да, утечка произойдет, причем в зависимости от окружающего кода - разная. Как избежать? Способов много. Один из простых - не использовать простые указатели, а использовать умные, которые автоматически занимаются управлением памятью.

Answer (score 3):

Разумеется произойдёт! Ведь будет неизвестен адрес первого выделенного участка (и удалить его не получится...)

и куда страшнее  будет  если ниже вызывается:

```
delete p1;
delete p2;
```

лекарство одно [умные указатели 1](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D3%EC%ED%FB%E9_%F3%EA%E0%E7%E0%F2%E5%EB%FC),
[умные указатели 2](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/)

и ещё `new+delete` это уже C++  а не C

Answer (score 2):

Собственно, в учебниках по C++, когда автор желает продемонстрировать читателю, что такое "утечка памяти", он часто приводит именно такой код. Даже если логически подумать, то все станет очевидно. **Пример без указателей:**

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
a=b;  // сможем ли мы теперь иметь дело с первоначальным значением переменной "a" ?
```

А если в переменной указатель, то то его значение будет утеряно, как единица в данном примере. Следовательно, контроль над значением утерян, как и само значение.